# How to modify a new application to run on an older android?

Tags: android

How to modify a new application to run on an older android? I have one app, which requies Android 5.1 or later. I have 4.4. How to make this app compatible with my version of Android? I can't upgrade system :(
Greetings :D

Comment: In your build.gradle set the minSdkVersion to 19

Comment: Where is this file?

Comment: And it isn't my app, but APK downloaded from internet

Comment: Then, you can't do anything.